# Ads on phonegap apps built on cloud

Tags: cordova, admob, ads

I have a app developed using https://build.phonegap.com/ , written purely on html ,css and js and compiled on cloud to the respective apps.How can i add ads like admob, airpush to something like this.

Answer (score 1):

Because Phonegap is written in HTML you can simply add the Admob HTML5 script, not the Java file, which is great because it's much faster and easier to do!

Just create an account with Admob or any of the other ad providers, and they'll give you a few lines of HTML you need to add to your project.